What is the difference between `serialize`,`try_to_vec` and `try_serialize` in anchor?
If I have an account let a : MyAccount and I try to serialize it to borsh, there's seemingly three ways to do this:
a.try_to_vec
a.try_serialize
a.serialize

Are these all the same?

No, they are not. try_to_vec and serialize are quite similar as try_to_vec calls serialize under the hood. The difference between these two is that serialize requires you to pass a writer where the serialized data should be written to whereas try_to_vec just creates a new Vec<u8> under the hood and passes that to serialize.
try_serialize is significantly different, as it's the only one out of the three that preprends the account data with the account discriminator:
let acc = MyAccount {};
println!("try_to_vec: {:?}", acc.try_to_vec().unwrap());
let mut w = vec![];
acc.try_serialize(&mut w).unwrap();
println!("try_serialize: {:?}", w);
let mut w2 = vec![];
acc.serialize(&mut w2).unwrap();
println!("serialize: {:?}", w2);

// Output:
try_to_vec: []
try_serialize: [197, 149, 223, 199, 86, 73, 227, 77] // This is the discriminator
serialize: []

The same applies for the deserialization functions anchor provides, MyAccount::deserialize (no discriminator expected) and MyAccount::try_deserialize (discriminator expected).
